# Avoiding Governor limits on test classes

Tags: unit-test, governorlimits, test-setup

We have a custom application created on the force.com platform which has a lot of unwanted SOQL Queries and DML Statements written in a poor format.

We are trying to stabilize the code now and looking for creating a test class which can run some valid business scenarios.
We have a test data creation class. When creating data in our test class, we are getting close to the soql and dml governor limit. Once the data creation is done, our actual test class which runs the scenarios fails on governor limits.

So my question is can I create 2 test methods, one where I can create test data in one context and another method to run my business scenarios which will have a different context?
That way I can get more limits and run my test classes

Comment: Including a `Test.startTest()` between the setup and code you are testing resets the limits. Also doing the setup in an `@TestSetup` method probably does the same thing (or may not). This helps somewhat but obviously only to some degree.

Comment: I think those limits consumed in `@TestSetup` still count against you.

Comment: @KeithC Whatcha know, you're right. Test.startTest in testSetup prevents it from eating up your governor limits... TIL.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I dunno if it's a bug, but Test.startTest in \@testSetup gives you a new set of governor limits that won't affect your unit tests.

Comment: @sfdcfox That sounds like a bug. Still pretty cool and maybe they won't fix it.

Comment: @AdrianLarson It never should have been a thing to begin with. testSetup is practically its own execution context, *and* they don't even let us preserve static variables so we have to burn a bunch of queries up front just to use it. Our testSetup method we use, for example, basically requires nearly 80 queries of total governor usage by the time we hit Test.startTest in our unit tests. I'm going to do some refactoring now...

Answer (score 12):

Set up your test data in @testSetup. To avoid using your test governor limits, start with Test.startTest():

```
@isTest class MyUnitTestClass {
  @testSetup static void testSetup() {
    Test.startTest();
    // Do your DML operations here
    Test.stopTest();
  }
  @isTest static void test() {
    // You have to re-query your records
    // Account a = [SELECT Id, Name... FROM Account]; etc...
    Test.startTest();
    // Test your business logic here
    Test.stopTest();
  }
}
```

Of course, this won't necessarily completely fix your problem, but it gives you a full extra set of governor limits for setting up your test data, which will probably help significantly.