# Test.startTest() in testSetup method

Tags: apex, unit-test, test-setup

An year ago I asked a [**question**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/160328/what-are-the-advantage-of-the-testsetup-annotation) regarding the advantages of using testSetUp annotation instead of having a method for common data and calling it in every test method. My main issue at the time with using testSetup method was if it issues 30 queries, every test method starts its life with only 70 queried remaining and on top of that the data created in it is unavailable in test methods. We have to explicitly query again.

I happened to notice that if I wrap the whole testSetup code between Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest(), the soql queries are not counted against the individual test methods and we can use Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest() again in the test methods.

Question:

Since this behavior is not documented, are there any negative effects from this approach?

**Example:**

```
@isTest
private class AvinashTest {

    @testSetup static void commonData(){
        Test.startTest();

        Account a = (Account) TestFactory.createSObject(new Account(), true);
        Contact c = (Contact) TestFactory.createSObject(new Contact(), true);
        Opportunity o = (Opportunity) TestFactory.createSObject(new Opportunity(AccountId=a.Id,StageName='Closed Lost', Channel_Type__c = 'Direct'), true);
        Product2 prod1 = (Product2) TestFactory.createSObject(new Product2(), true);
        PricebookEntry pbe = (PricebookEntry) TestFactory.createSObject(new PricebookEntry(Product2Id = prod1.Id), true);
        Asset ast = (Asset) TestFactory.createSObject(new Asset( Product2Id = prod1.Id, AccountId = a.Id), true);

        System.Debug('**commonData**'+Limits.getQueries()); //Returns 16

        Test.stopTest();
    }

    @isTest static void demoMethodOne() {

        System.Debug('**demoMethodOne**'+Limits.getQueries()); //Returns 0

        Test.startTest();

        Opportunity o = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity LIMIT 1];

        Test.stopTest();

    }

    @isTest static void demoMethodTwo() {

        System.Debug('**demoMethodTwo**'+Limits.getQueries()); //Returns 0

        Test.startTest();

        Opportunity o = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity LIMIT 1];

        Test.stopTest();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a method you would have known about if you'd seen my [previous answer on the subject](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/176800). We use this internally because without using this technique, we continually run into governor limits on some of our larger tests. Several developers, including myself, have independently found this feature, and it's allowed us to continue building our internal applications without more aggressive optimization of our code. So far, we've observed no negative consequences from this technique, but have enjoyed more reliable tests and the ability to insert a lot more standardized test data than was previously possible.

Comment: Thank you. I used to avoid testSetup methods when there are large data sets since I need to query for every object again in test methods.

Comment: @Avinash Yes, I've created [an idea for that](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dj51AAC). Even so, even if you have to query the records back, you still save on DML rows/statements and initial set up query rows/statements, so it's better than not using it at all.

Comment: I agree. At the time I didn't know about this behavior since it is not documented anywhere. I asked a question about pros and cons of the testSetup back in Feb 2017. Many developers shared their opinions...but no one discussed this approach.

Comment: If these methods are used with the only intent to create a new set of limits, shouldn't they be renamed to something more intuitive? 

Test.OpenLimitSet / Test.CloseLimitSet (_or something like that_)?

Comment: @toadgeek Test.startTest is designed to give you the ability to simulate the start of a transaction (where you'd normally have no limits used), and Test.stopTest has several purposes, notably triggering asynchronous code to run synchronously. It just so happens that in testSetup is has the effect of resetting the governor limits for the tests themselves. I feel this technique should not be necessary; testSetup should automatically have its own set of limits, because it cripples the limits of the unit test.

Comment: Yes, I agree one million percent.

Answer (score 0):

As of five days ago, I have a test class that fails because it uses Test.startTest() in a @testSetup method, and the other methods then test classes that make callouts. Previously this test class was working fine for over a year.

When Test.starttest() is used it is throwing the error "System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out." When Test.starttest() is removed from the @TestSetup method, the error goes away.

Apparently they messed something up so that DML used within Test.startTest() in a @testSetup method is somehow being treated as the same transaction as the callouts which happen in the actual test methods, which of course is totally wrong. It is treating it as if DML statements are being made before a callout in a single transaction, which is not allowed. Definitely seems like a Salesforce bug, and I have a ticket in to them.