# Test two different scheduled apex classes from one test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, scheduled-apex

I have two different scheduled classes that I am trying to schedule from a single test class. A simplification is the first class creates a set of records, and then the second class does something else with those records.

I can write a test class for either of them, but since they are so closely linked I thought it would be good to create a single test class that tests them both.

First When I scheduled the job with `String jobId = System.schedule('ScheduledApexTest',CRON_EXP, new exampleClass());` and then stop the test with `Test.stopTest();`, nothing happens. The TimesTriggered stays 0. This is kind of a separate issue, but I've been testing using the method below.

```
test.startTest();

SchedulableContext sc;
exampleClass1 EC1 = new exampleClass1();
EC.execute(sc);

SchedulableContext sc2;
exampleClass2 EC2 = new exampleClass2();
EC2.execute(sc2);

test.stopTest();
```

For some reason when I do this, it seems to run exampleClass1 twice and doesn't run exampleClass2.
I also tried using only one schedulablecontext in both calls, but that gives a similar error.

Each of them works by themselves, but it acts weird when I do both together. Is this something that can be done, or do I just have to do this in two different test classes?

Comment: are the execute() methods delegating work to further async transactions? The above should work fine

Comment: Why would you not test them separately?

Comment: My first scheduled class is a custom lead conversion, and the second one creates opportunities based on lead and contact fields. I wanted the test records for the opp builder to exactly mirror what was created from the lead converter. But I didn't want to put the whole lead converter in the test class, and I'm struggling to reference it for the same reasons above.

Answer (score 1):

You can really only test *one* asynchronous thing per unit test. Use two unit tests. Both unit test methods can be in the same class, and you can use @TestSetup if you want to set up data common to both tests in order to preserve execution time/governor limits. If you do decide to use @TestSetup, keep also in mind that @TestSetup will [eat up your unit test governor limits unless you call Test.startTest() first](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/176800/2984), so make sure you do that.

Comment: When I try this I get an error saying "No more than one executeBatch can be called from within a test method". The documentation usually says this happens when having more than 200 records in a batch, but that's definitely not the case here so I think each class being batchable is also an issue now.

Comment: @denvergreene It can also happen if two batches are called in the same test method. They need to be called in separate unit tests.